# TYPE_E_TYPEMISMATCH changing Metadata Windows Universal App

Tags: metadata, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, type-mismatch, win-universal-app

I want to overwrite the System.Photo.DateTaken value. This is my method:

```
private async void EditMetadata(uint rateNumber, DateTime newDate)
    {
        var memStream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var encoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(memStream, _decoder);

        var propertySet = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPropertySet();

        var ratingValue = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTypedValue(rateNumber, Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.UInt32);
        try
        {
            var dateValue = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTypedValue(newDate, Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.DateTime);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        propertySet.Add("System.Rating", ratingValue);
        //propertySet.Add("System.Photo.DateTaken", dateValue);

        try
        {
            await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(propertySet);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            switch (err.HResult)
            {
                case unchecked((int)0x88982F41): // WINCODEC_ERR_PROPERTYNOTSUPPORTED
                    // The file format does not support this property.
                    break;
                default:
                    throw err;
            }
        }
    }
```

There is no problem by setting the rating, but if I call this:

```
var dateValue = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTypedValue(newDate, Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.DateTime);
```

then I get this error message:

```
Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028CA0 (TYPE_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
```

I don't know why?
The DateCreated has the DataTime type.

Comment: Exact the same Problem here. But I'm building for Widnows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue and then I found a solution. Use this code instead:

```
var dateValue = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTypedValue(
                  Windows.Foundation.PropertyValue.CreateDateTime(
                    new DateTimeOffset(newDate)
                  ),
                  Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.DateTime
                );

propertySet.Add("System.Photo.DateTaken", dateValue);
```